# NodeJs: How to catch unhandled exception in asyc functions with global filter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, nestjs

First of all I am fairly new to JS world so please bear with my naïve question.

I have a controller method `getSequence` which is making an external http call. I have induces an exception in the `.then()` block. It seems that even though I see the unhandled exception error message in the console of my VS Code. The postman from which I called `getSequence` seems to just keep on waiting infinitely.

The idea behind added global exception filters was that I shouldn't have to write catch blocks all over the place. But it seems that added catch block in this case doesn't make any different anyways.
BTW I am using NestJs.

```
 @Get("getSequence")
  async getSequence(@Body() query: SequenceQueries,@Res() res) {

//an http call to external api
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2',
      headers: { 
        'caller': 'samurai', 
        'Cookie': 'sails.sid=s%3AqJIPTqAEXcq1iYIfDtUbvMm02pIsNKSf.4FT26ad2GRBlnVE%2BMOMsy9Boxk2zTm%2FPQTdstsMWKi4'
      }
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      throw new Error("something really went wrong!"); //deliberating an error
        res.send(response.data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error(error); 
    });

    // return await this.sequenceService.getNextSequenceNew(query)
    }
   }
```

**main.ts**

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalFilters(new FallbackExceptionFilter(),new BadRequestExceptionFilter());
  await app.listen(3000);
```

**FallbackException.ts**

```
@Catch()
export class FallbackExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    protected applicationRef?: HttpServer<any, any>;
    protected httpAdapterHost?: HttpAdapterHost<AbstractHttpAdapter<any, any, any>>;    
    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
        console.log('exception', exception)
        //throw new BaseException();
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp(),
        response = ctx.getResponse(),
        request = ctx.getRequest();
        response.status(500).json(new BaseException(request,response,exception))
    }
    
}
```

**BadRequestException.ts**

```
@Catch(BadRequestException)
export class BadRequestExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: BadRequestException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();
    console.log(response)
    response
      .status(200)
      .json(new ValidationException(request,response,exception));
  }
}
```

Comment: When writing `async getSequence`, you should use `await` and `try`/`catch` instead of `.then()` and `.catch()`.

Comment: You forgot to `return` the promise from your `getSequence` function. Only that way, its rejection can be handled by nestjs and passed to your `FallbackExceptionFilter`.

Comment: Btw, `BadRequestException` should respond with a 400 status not a 200 one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the error you throw inside your `then`-handler will be turned into a rejected promise which the next `catch`-handler will catch. In there, however, you re-throw the error which will again turn into a rejected promise, that is not caught anywhere. This is why you see the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

To fix this, you can do the following: Replace the promise with `async/await` and wrap the call with a `try/catch` statement. Something like this:

```
@Get("getSequence")
async getSequence(@Body() query: SequenceQueries,@Res() res) {
    // ...
    try {
            const response = await axios(config);
            throw new Error("something really went wrong!"); // deliberately throw error
            res.send(response.data);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            // re-throw error
            throw err;
    }
        
}
```

The rethrown error from the catch block should now be correctly caught by the NestJS exception filter.

EDIT:

If you really want to use promises `then/catch` handlers inside your `async` method, you need to return the promise (which will be a rejected promise in this case):

```
return axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      throw new Error("something really went wrong!"); //deliberating an error
        res.send(response.data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error)
       throw error; 
    });
```

NestJS should now handle this rejected promise and invoke the fallback error filter.

Comment: With await, i think don't even have to write try and catch since I have the global filter to catch errors.  But I am worried that some developer might use .then() instead of await approach. In which case application might swallow errors.

Comment: That's true, I just thought you wanted to explicitly catch the error, log it and re-throw. I've also edited the answer to show how you can do it with promise `then/catch` handlers.

Comment: Where are you returning rejected promise? How is `throw new Error(error);` different from` throw err;`

Comment: There's no difference, `throw error` would actually be better, as there's no reason to wrap the error in another error. The difference is the `return` before `axios(...)´.